# If a site accepts uploads via drag and drop, can I make a local browse button instead, e.g. with TamperMonkey?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, local, file-browser

I upload images to a a few sites every day, for work. I've got some of this work automated with autohotkey. But one site only offers drag-and-drop as an upload method, and it's a small hassle. Regardless of whether I can automate it, I would prefer a browse button.

Is it possible to somehow implement local javascript that creates a browse button to upload these files, or is that expecting too much / blocked for security?

Prefer a solution with Chrome.